# Ruby: sub/gsub at a particular line OR before/after a pattern

Tags: ruby, string, design-patterns, replace, gsub

I know that I can replace text as below in a file

```
File.write(file, File.read(file).gsub(/text/, "text_to_replace"))
```

Can we also use sub/gsub to:-

- Replace a string on a particular line number (useful when there is a same string at different locations in a file)

**Example**

```
 root@vikas:~# cat file.txt
 fix grammatical or spelling errors
 clarify meaning without changing it
 correct minor mistakes
 add related resources or links
 root@box27:~#
```

I want to insert some text at 3rd line

```
 root@vikas:~# cat file.txt
 fix grammatical or spelling errors
 clarify meaning without changing it
 Hello, how are you ?
 correct minor mistakes
 add related resources or links
 root@box27:~
```

- Replace a string on the line just before/after matching a pattern

**Example**

```
 root@vikas:~# cat file.txt
 fix grammatical or spelling errors
 clarify meaning without changing it
 correct minor mistakes
 add related resources or links
 root@box27:~#
```

I want to search 'minor mistakes' and put text 'Hello, how are you ?' before that.

```
 root@vikas:~# cat file.txt
 fix grammatical or spelling errors
 clarify meaning without changing it
 Hello, how are you ?
 correct minor mistakes
 add related resources or links
 root@box27:~
```

Comment: You'd like to give some input sample and expect output.

Comment: @BMW I am not looking for a particular example, but a generic method. Something similar to through 'sed' command in Unix.

Comment: Looks good now, see my answer

Comment: @BMW Perfect. I thought there would be some one liner thing like sed with sub/gsub. Thanks for your time and efforts on this. I am also pasting modifications in your code to make it work to insert text after a pattern match and at a particular line as well.

Comment: Good news. Then you need vote it or accept it if that's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.

```
File.open("file.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
  if line =~ /minor mistakes/
     puts "Hello, how are you ?"
  end
  puts "#{line}"
end
```

Here is ruby one-liner.

```
ruby -pe 'puts "Hello, how are you ?" if $_ =~ /minor mistakes/' < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find this functionality in a gem like Thor. Check out the documentation for the `inject_into_file` method here:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/erikhuda/thor/master/Thor/Actions#inject_into_file-instance_method.

Here is the source code for the method:

https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/067f6638f95bd000b0a92cfb45b668bca5b0efe3/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb#L24-L32

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to match on line `n` (offset from zero):

```
def match_line_i(fname, linenbr regex)
  IO.foreach(fname).with_index { |line,i| 
    return line[regex] if i==line_nbr }
end
```

or

```
return scan(regex) if i==line_nbr }
```

depending on your requirements.

If you wish to match on a given line, then return the previous line, for application of `gsub` (or whatever):

```
def return_previous_line(fname, regex)
  last_line = nil
  IO.foreach(fname) do |line|
    line = f.readline
    return last_line if line =~ regex
    last_line = line
  end
end
```

Both methods return `nil` if there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as there is no such option available with sub/gsub, I am pasting here my code (with slight modifications to BMW's code) for all three options. Hopefully, this helps someone in a similar situation.

1. Insert text before a pattern
2. Insert text after a pattern
3. Insert text at a specific line number

   ```
   root@box27:~# cat file.txt
   fix grammatical or spelling errors
   clarify meaning without changing it
   correct minor mistakes 
   add related resources or links
   always respect the original author
   root@box27:~#

   root@box27:~# cat ruby_script
   puts "#### Insert text before a pattern"
   pattern = 'minor mistakes'
   File.open("file.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
     puts "Hello, how are you ?" if line =~ /#{pattern}/
     puts "#{line}"
   end

   puts "\n\n#### Insert text after a pattern"
   pattern = 'meaning without'
   File.open("file.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
   found = 'no'
     if line =~ /#{pattern}/
       puts "#{line}"
       puts "Hello, how are you ?"
       found = 'yes'
     end
   puts "#{line}" if found == 'no'
   end

   puts "\n\n#### Insert text at a particular line"
   insert_at_line = 3
   line_number = 1
   File.open("file.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
     puts "Hello, how are you ?" if line_number == insert_at_line
     line_number += 1
     puts "#{line}"
   end
   root@box27:~#
   ```